# Can we ignore intent if we recognize the extent?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

I am not sure whether the formulation of my question is adequate, but I hope I'll make it clear enough. As a mathematics student, I have come to notice that some mathematical concepts are not defined through *meaning*, but through *properties*. Some abstract topological space is a *Stone-Cech compactification* if it behaves like one, essentially.

And I have begun to notice this behaviour in the real world. Concepts such as music genres are sometimes not entirely described by meaning, but by the musical pieces that adapt to it. That is, please correct me if I'm wrong, music genres are born when there begins to exist music that belongs to it. Does this mean that extent comes before intent in this case?

In general, are we able to form a concept without know exactly what it means (the intent), but by just looking at the set of things to which this abstract concept applies? Does this mean that intent and extent are in some sense equivalent? Could someone please point me to philosophy or linguistics references so that I can try to understand this situation better?

Comment: What does it mean to be defined "by meaning" vs "through properties" ?

Comment: What would defining a concept "through meaning" look like exactly? A concept gets a meaning by getting defined, getting a meaning through meaning sounds very circular. And its defining properties (intension) are distinct from the set of things that fall under it (extension), so it is unclear what you are asking. Coextensive concepts can have different intensions, e.g. black US president and Barack Obama.

Comment: Having noticed the incredible number of genres the Sonique computer app let you classify tracks under back in the day, I sympathize with your wonder. And indeed, sometimes we ostensively define terms. We take certain examples to be representative. So yes, sometimes extension precedes intension as such. Maybe not absolutely and completely, there's still mental processing going on in the background that might motivate certain abstractions from exemplars over others (maybe we define a given cedar tree by sight of it but that it's a tree is preloaded) but the emphasis is on the exemplars.

Comment: 'genres' are taxonomic classifications only.

Comment: Putnam has a [vector theory of meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilary_Putnam#Theory_of_meaning), where extension is one of the four components. Another one is the "stereotype", common descriptions/properties by which exemplars are recognized. For many colloquial uses knowing the stereotype (not extension) is enough, maybe that is what you have in mind. But it doesn't give the full "meaning".